# Parse file saving error,“”Unable to encode an unsaved parsefile in User

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to sign up a user with a picture and I keep getting the error "Unable to encode an unsaved parsefile", And when I click save again it says a user is already signing up but it never gets to parse.

My code is as follows

```
imageToBeSent = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imageToBeSent.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,5, stream);    
byte[] imageRec = stream.toByteArray();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profile.png", imageRec);


file.saveInBackground();

Intent fromFirstSignup = getIntent();
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.put("Name", fromFirstSignup.getStringExtra("Name"));
user.put("Surname", fromFirstSignup.getStringExtra("Surname"));
user.put("Department", fromFirstSignup.getStringExtra("Department"));
user.put("JobTitle", fromFirstSignup.getStringExtra("JobTitle"));
user.setEmail(fromFirstSignup.getStringExtra("EmailAddress"));
user.put("ProfilePictures", file);
user.setUsername(usernametxt);
user.setPassword(passwordtxt);

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
        }
    }
}
```

The initializing of other variables may not show. I did look at the other questions similar to this but none helped with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re getting this error because you cannot attach an unsaved PFFile in a PFObject/PFUser/PFWhatever.

You have to wait until the file.saveInBackground finishes and then save your User later.

I suggest that you implement the file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock, and put your Sign Up code inside the completion blocks.

Comment: Thank you I actually used file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {}); and created a separate method for user.signUpInBackground and then called that method after inside saveInBackground and it worked.

Comment: Oh yes the same way you are explaining it, Thank you